# Parser to convert data from plain text to XML

Tags: php, parsing

I am amateur PHP/Javascript programmer trying to create a parser to convert data from plain text to XML.

The layout of the plaintext varies from document to document but the content is the same in each, it is just how it is represented.

I have half way written a custom parser to convert the data, and would like to know if I am going the right away about it?

I try and read about recursive descent parsers, and LALR parsers but it seems to go over my head, so I am wondering if I am wasting my time by coming up with my own method of doing it?

I have tokenised each of the important elements, scored (according to information stored in the pattern) and tallied up the frequency of each pattern.

Using the score (It is done by adding 1,2,4,8 etc for each bit of info captured) it is possible to weed out potential duplicate patterns/information (As the layout of the information will be a set format and repeated throughout the plaintext) and the frequency it is possible to discard those patterns which are unlikely to convey any meaning.

Is this the correct way to go or am I creating a maintainability hazard?

I am using PHP by the way.

Comment: I assume that you couldn't just replace specific patterns with some seperating XML code?

Comment: Can you post the plain text files? (or if they're big, a small portion of it). Also indicate how the transformed XML should look like.